# USB hard drive won't remount after power outage

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, lubuntu

My home server has a USB hard drive plugged to it. Once in a while, the breakers jump or there are power outages. Since my server is a laptop, it keeps chugging along, but the rest of the hardware (network, periphericals) do a power cycle.

My hard drive is set to auto-mount in fstab, but after a power outage, the drive remains listed, but isn't accessible. I get IO errors when trying to access it, and why I try to unmount it, I get "umount: mount disagrees with the fstab". **Calling `mount -a` or rebooting fixes the problem.**

This did not happen with Linux Mint, but it does with this minimal Lubuntu install. How can I solve it?

```
UUID=bb14889e-70de-45f4-882a-5ef45708d283 /media/external1      ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro,nobootwait 0       1
```

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't understand why there is a difference in `Mint` and `Lubuntu`, I recommend you react to power outages with running the command which solves your problem:

```
mount -a
```

You can either run this command periodically or poll the battery status:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

**NOTE:** Your device may be different. You can confirm like so using `upower -d`:

```
$ upower -d | grep Devic
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ADP1
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
```

Or simply check if there are errors on the drive:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while [[ 1 ]]; do
   ls /mnt/external1
   ret=$?
   sleep 1m
   if [ $ret -neq 0]; then
     mount -a 
   fi
 done
```

`$?` is the return value of `ls` which will be `>0` if there were errors.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to get your disk mounted by `udev` rules instead of `fstab` entry. This way whenever an outrage happens, your laptop will notice that a USB device was unplugged, and unmount the drive. Once the power comes back, it will detect that USB device again, and remount the drive.

Here's an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512524/mounting-usb-disks-automatically) dealing with mounting USB drives on connection specifically for lubuntu.